# Gitbash versus Command Prompt (Windows)

Tags: cmd, git-bash

What is the difference between running commands on Gitbash (on windows) and the command prompt? I installed Gitbash on my Windows machine and using the mkdir function does not create a new directory (a folder that I can see).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between Git GUI, Git Bash, Git CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034549/difference-between-git-gui-git-bash-git-cmd)

Answer (score 1):

- [git bash](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/share/WinGit/Git%20Bash.vbs) opens an msys bash session
- [git-cmd.bat](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat) opens a CMD session

Both set `HOME` properly (it is not set by default in Windows, as opposed to Unix/Linux).
And both add Git to the `%PATH%`.

They are package in [Git For Windows](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/releases) (with a [64bits coming soon](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/), with a more recent bash).

Answer (score 1):

in gitbash mingw64 for windows 10 when you are in c:, mkdir creates new directory without problems.

For do it, you can go to c: by typing *cd /c/* and after, press enter key. When you are in C change to your work directory with CD command, and type *mkdir yournewdirectoryname*. It works for me.