# Difference between Git GUI, Git Bash, Git CMD

Tags: git, bash, cmd

What is the  difference between **Git GUI**, **Git Bash** and **Git CMD**?
I'm a beginner, and for doing my installations I usually find myself using both git bash and git CMD

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Git CMD is just like regular Windows command prompt with the `git` command. It lets you use all of Git features through command line. Useful if you are already familiar with Windows cmd and you only work on Windows.

Git Bash emulates a [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)) environment on windows. It lets you use all git features in command line plus most of [standard unix commands](https://ss64.com/bash/). Useful if you are used to Linux and want to keep the same habits.

Git GUI is a **G**raphical **U**ser **I**nterface letting you use Git without touching command line. It is an alternative among other Git clients. Since Git GUI is very minimal, you could also look at [other alternatives](https://git-scm.com/download/gui/windows) if GUIs interest you.

It is up to you to decide which you want to use. As many others, I recommend you to learn Git with command line before switching to a graphical interface. If you don't know which to choose between Git Bash and Git CMD, I'd go for Git Bash since bash is a really useful tool to learn.

Comment: One thing I think should be noted, at the back end they all use the same code. So there is no chance you will put your repository into a state with one tool that's incompatible with another. At least, I was under the impression this was the case.

Comment: The [release notes](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) for `v2.19.1 ` say `Git CMD is deprecated as of this Git for Windows version. The default is to have git.exe in the PATH anyway, so there is no noticeable difference between CMD and Git CMD`I have no idea what the difference between git and git cmd were.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler I believe you could choose not to install git in the regular CMD to avoid some issues.

Comment: @BernhardDöbler What a rash statement of theirs. There is a _very_ noticeable difference between CMD and Git CMD in that Git CMD uses a Unicode-ready TrueType font by default. There's an installer option to set it as a default for Windows CMD as well.

Answer (score 22):

[What is difference between GIT GUI, GIT BASH and GIT CMD?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-GIT-GUI-GIT-BASH-and-GIT-CMD)

Someone has asked it before in Quora.

> **Git Bash**:
>
> Bash is a Unix shell and command language, and is the
> default shell on Linux (Ubuntu etc.) and OS X. In laymen terms, the
> git which runs on the terminal of any Linux device is known as git
> bash.
>
> **Git CMD**:
>
> (Command Line prompt) is the command-line interpreter on
> Windows operating systems. Sort of an equivalent to the bad-ass
> terminal in Linux, when you install git on windows and you are used to
> using command line, one uses cmd to run git commands.
>
> There is not at all any difference when it comes to git commands when
> you use either of the above. I would prefer the terminal over cmd any
> day, but if you like Windows for conventional reasons, I have used
> Cygwin to give me the terminal like feeling on Windows.
>
> **Git GUI**:
>
> Essentially aimed at people who don't like the coding on
> black screens a.k.a the command line. It provides a Graphical user
> interface to run the git commands you like for eg. if you are
> commiting some changes from your local repository to the staging
> queue, you would just have to click a button to commit the changes
> whereas the git command is 'git commit -m ""

I think it is clear enough for your question.

Comment: As a 2year+ member you should know what the help says on link only answers. Please (re-)read [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 6):

Git is a version control system [Version Control System](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control)

Git **Bash** - It's a Bash based Terminal, [**Bash is a Unix based Terminal**] which simply means that user can directly use `Unix` commands in that Bash terminal

Git **GUI** - Used for on system as an IDE if you don't have an IDE or want to work in Github like environment but offline, then Git GUI is useful. If you are using VScode or Sublime editors they now have added a plugin for `Git` commands. So it is also an option for you to rather than installing the Git **GUI**

Git **CMD** `deprecated` - Mainly used by Windows users because it also has some Git command features user can use directly, which is an issue while using a Windows **Command Prompt** [CMD].

Best Application of Git Version Control System is **Github**

[**Guide to Github**](https://guides.github.com/activities/hello-world/)

About -----
[**Bash**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

[**Git GUI**](https://git-scm.com/download/gui/windows)

[**Git Bash**](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

[**Git CMD**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-The-Command-Line)