# I cannot log in heroku from command Line

Tags: heroku, command

[Screenshot of Error messages in command Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIG9t.png)

I installed heroku CLI and git 
Then I try to login heroku from command line(commmand:" heroku login")

But After I put my email address and push Enter key, this error comes.

Could someone help and explain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the essential binaries. Try installing git bash or cygwin. Run the same command from respective terminal. Heroku CLI might not be supported over windows command prompt.

https://git-scm.com/download/win

http://www.cygwin.com/install.html

Comment: The installer in the link I have shared installs git along with a windows compatible shell i.e. git bash. Git bash is just like windows command prompt, nothing but a command interpreter. Git bash has a built-in interpreter for "sh" command which you are missing in windows default CLI.

Comment: I appreciate you. I could logged in from Git bash terminal.And also  I checked Git CMD is working or not Then This was not working. Do you know  what is the difference Git bash terminal and Git CMD terminal?

Comment: What is Git CMD terminal? From where did you get it?
Can you share any link?

Comment: When you install Git, it will be downloaded in your system with Git GUI and Git bash

And I found the differences ,,,,,,,,,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034549/difference-between-git-gui-git-bash-git-cmd

Comment: Ok. So it's the same reason. Git CMD is nothing but an emulator for windows powershell which extends support for interpreting git commands on powershell. This extension only limits to commands which Git requires. Heroku-CLI is different from Git CLI. 
All Git commands might not require `sh.exe` but Heroku definitely needs. As explained `Git bash` comes bundled with bash (provider of sh simulator on windows).